# SQL - Statistical Linkage Keys - Add characters to a string if its not the required length

Tags: sql

I am creating a statistical linkage key and I have succefully done that part. The problem I am facing is some peoples names are not long enough so they fall short at 13 characters. I need to be able to pad a "2" to the end of it to make it the required 14 characters. Below is my code which works, I'm just struggling with padding only those that fall short to add a number "2" to the end of it. For example if somones name was very short an the key only had 10 characters i would add four '2' to it and so on. I really hjope I ave added enough information. Thanks in advance

```
isnull(SUBSTRING(rtrim(ltrim(replace(hhm.Surname,'''',''))),2,1),'2')
  +isnull(SUBSTRING(rtrim(ltrim(replace(hhm.Surname,' ',''))),3,1),'2')
  +isnull(SUBSTRING(rtrim(ltrim(replace(hhm.Surname,' ',''))),5,1),'2')
  +isnull(SUBSTRING(rtrim(ltrim(replace(hhm.forenames,'''',''))),2,1),'2')
  +isnull(SUBSTRING(rtrim(ltrim(replace(hhm.forenames,' ',''))),3,1),'2')
  +case when hhm.[Date of Birth] is NULL
        then '00000000'
        else replace(CONVERT(char(10),hhm.[Date of Birth],103),'/','')
   end
  +isnull(case when hhm.Gender = 'M'
        then '1'
        else '2'
   end,'2')                                         as 'Statistical Linkage Key'
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes across this and was wondering what the answer was I figued it out eventually. I just needed to add in a COALESCE(NULLIF(filed),''),'2') as you can see below.

```
,COALESCE(NULLIF(SUBSTRING(rtrim(ltrim(replace(hhm.Surname,'''',''))),2,1),''),'2')
  +COALESCE(NULLIF(SUBSTRING(rtrim(ltrim(replace(hhm.Surname,' ',''))),3,1),''),'2')
  +COALESCE(NULLIF(SUBSTRING(rtrim(ltrim(replace(hhm.Surname,' ',''))),5,1),''),'2')
  +COALESCE(NULLIF(SUBSTRING(rtrim(ltrim(replace(hhm.forenames,'''',''))),2,1),''),'2')
  +COALESCE(NULLIF(SUBSTRING(rtrim(ltrim(replace(hhm.forenames,' ',''))),3,1),''),'2')
  +case when hhm.[Date of Birth] is NULL
        then '00000000'
        else replace(CONVERT(char(10),hhm.[Date of Birth],103),'/','')
   end
  +isnull(case when hhm.Gender = 'M'
        then '1'
        else '2'
   end,'2')                                         as 'Statistical Linkage Key'
```